# Swift - Finding duplicate Json data and merging

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift3

I'm using swiftyjson to mess around with my json data.

Currently, i'm receiving data that has values I want to merge together. (it'll make more sense if you take a look at the example below. I'v tried many different approaches such as using a for loop to go through the JSON data but that duplicates everything. I have also tried changing my json to a 2d array then filtering it, but it seems like that is complicating things. There has to be an easier way...

```
var jsondata = {
{
    fruit: "APPLE"
    amount: 10
},{
    fruit: "Mango"
    amount: 5 
},{
    fruit: "APPLE"
    amount: 5 
},{
    fruit: "Mango"
    amount: 5 
},{
    fruit: "orange"
    amount: 500
}
}


var NEWjsondata = 
{
    {
    fruit: "APPLE"
    amount: 15
    },
    {
    fruit: "Mango"
    amount: 10
    },
    {
    fruit: "orange"
    amount: 500
    }
}
```

My approach

```
var arr = ["Apple","Mango","Orange"]
for (key,json) in jsondata {
arr.append(json["fruit"])
if arr.contains(json["fruit"]){
json["amount"] = json["amount"] + json["amount"]
}}
```

Comment: Thats not valid JSON data. [Here](https://app.quicktype.io) you can see whether its valid.

Comment: @Purpose this is a pseudocode mate :]

Comment: show the code you have tried. create a new dictionary that can support the type of item in the array and then iterate over the array, if the "fruit" is already there, add the amount, if not add the fruit and amount.

Comment: @Scriptable updated the post with my approach. The issue with your suggestion is that it'll cause duplicate entries to be added. This was the first approach i took.

Comment: not if you check for fruit existence first.

Comment: @Scriptable I am. I am appending to the arr variable as i loop through the json file in the for loop. Take a look at my update. I'm checking to see if the arr contains the next fruit already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going through all the dictionaries and extract from each fruit-name and amount and then make a new entry in the result-dictionary or add to the prior amount counted already.

```
func mergedDict(dictionaries: [[String: Any]]) -> [String: Int] {
    guard dictionaries.count != 0 else { return [:] }

    var result = [String: Int]()

    dictionaries.forEach { dict in
        var name: String?
        var amount: Int?
        dict.forEach{ arg in
            switch arg.key {
            case "fruit":
                name = arg.value as! String
            case "amount":
                amount = arg.value as! Int
            default:
                fatalError("does not exist.")
            }
        }

        guard let fruit = name else { fatalError("name is nil.") }
        guard let newAmount = amount else { fatalError("amount is nil.") }

        guard let priorAmount = result[fruit] else {
            result[fruit] = newAmount
            return
        }
        result[fruit] = priorAmount + newAmount
    }

    return result
}
```

Making FruitStruct conform to the Codable protocol allows encoder.encode to take our FruitStruct-array. The struct mimics the JSON we want. One may add `enum CodingKeys` to change the mapping from the struct to the actual JSON.

```
struct FruitStruct: Codable {
    let fruit: String
    let amount: Int
}

func json(fromDict: [String: Int]) throws -> String {
    let fruitStructs = fromDict.map { arg in
        return FruitStruct(fruit: arg.key, amount: arg.value)
    }

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

    let data = try encoder.encode(fruitStructs)

    guard let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
        fatalError("failed to decode json-Data to String with utf8.")
    }
    return string
}
```

Comment: @iloveStackOverflow You can create a `struct FruitStruct { let fruit: String; let amount: Int}`, map the mergedDict to [FruitStruct] and encode that with a JSONEncoder. Can you do it or do you need more guidance?

Comment: Btw.. there is a .prettyPrint setting on the JSONEncoder.

Comment: It's okay i'll figure it out. Thank you once again :]

Comment: actually yes, I need more guidance in regards to struct fruit. Attempted it myself but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @iloveStackOverflow For this you have to read up on Encodable, CodingKeys and the map function. You should know .filter, .map, .sorted, .enumerated, .forEach by heart so read up on them too. They make life a whole lot easier. Map uses generics to try to determine the output type. Updated the post.

Comment: OK will do. And i'm assuming "toJson" is suppose to take in a parameter of [[String:Int]] rather then [String:Int] since i'll be passing in the return result from mergeDict into it correct.

Comment: @iloveStackOverflow I think you have it the wrong way around, but yes the output from mergedDict goes into toJSON. Don‘t forget to look into the topics, otherwise I‘ll be sad. ;)